# Collection view change cell size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change the height of the cells in a `UICollectionView` when the cell is selected.

I managed to change the height however, when I select a cell the `y` position of the others does not change causing the cell selected to overlap the others.

How could tell the other cells to change y position the a cell height is modified?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let detailsCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? UserDetailsCell {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .TransitionCurlUp, animations: { 

                detailsCell.frame.size.height = 300

                }, completion: nil)

        }


        print(indexPath.row)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here it that you are treating a single cell/item individualy, you should just use autolayout to do all the work.

Define the size of the cell/item on the delegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        if selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
            return 300
        }
    }
    return 40
}
```

And in the selection, you just force an update on the layout.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! however in collect view delegate i count find `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: If you can't just use a UItableView, you going to have to create a UICollectionViewFlowLayout it is much more work, I do recommend to migrate to UITableView if possible.

Comment: Check this delegate:  collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/

Comment: I have migrated to UITableView and it is works very good.. thank you!